# Application Loader succeed with Signiant but fails with DAV

Tags: ios, xcode7, application-loader

I build a simple App with Xcode 7.1.1, archive it and export it with the organizer as a .ipa file.
When I try to upload this ipa to ituneconnect with Application Loader 3.3.
with DAV protocol only, the application Loader fails with a mysterious "An error occurred uploading to the App Store". On itune Connect the build is available in the Activity section with an forever "Processing" state.
When I upload with Signiant protocol, everything works fine...

FYI, I do need the DAV protocol as I'm behind a firewall in normal situation without rights on it.

Answer (score 0):

This happened many times with me ....
I think problem with app loader and apple server ...

Work around for this is to simply upload again ...or do proper setting in app loader preference as per your network ....